# Dojo datagrid - getSelected() of row that has not been drawn

Tags: javascript, datagrid, dojo, grid, selection

I'm trying to select rows dynamically on a datagrid using the `grid.selection.setSeleted()` and `grid.selection.getSeleted()` methods.

I can select rows that are currently undrawn (i.e you must use the horizontal scroll bar to see them).  But when I try to get the row contents using `grid.selection.getSeleted()`, the array returns `nulls` instead of the row data.

Is there any way to get the selected row data even if it is not currently drawn? Although it's slower can I force dojo to draw the entire grid, even if some of it is not displayed?

Comment: Can you add some code to show what you have tried? Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have al look : http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.8/dojox/grid/DataGrid.html#working-with-selections

It's a good example how to use getSelected()

and this is a Post from the dojo Forum. It discribes an error that's maybe familiar to yours.

http://dojo-toolkit.33424.n3.nabble.com/dojox-grid-DataGrid-selection-getSelected-odd-behaivour-td3941395.html

Regards